# TextIO doesn't import to my project

Tags: java, class, textinput

Hello dear professionals,
I'm a student. I'm sure it's a stupid questions, but I'm still stuck.

I have to import TextIO to my project to read some data from a file. I put TextIO.java file to src folder, where Main class file is and Main class is a class I write code in. But my project still doesn't let me to use TextIO functions.

Its written everywhere that:

If you add TextIO to the same package as the class that uses it, then TextIO will be automatically available to that class. If TextIO is in a different named package, you have to add an "import" statement to the other class to make TextIO available to it.

But it doesn't work for me. I use IntelliJ IDEA and Mac OS, if it's important.

Thank you.

Comment: Java source folder structure needs to follow package. If the full package path of `TextIO.java` is `com.test.TestIO`, then you need to create `com` folder in `src` folder, then `test` folder inside `com`, then put `TestIO.java` inside `test`. This rule will apply to that `Main.java` as well in the same manner.

Comment: Thank you, Jai. Unfortunately, I have a com.company folder in my src folder, and both Main.class and TextIO.java are inside. Still the same result. Or I should check a path of TextIO.java file and create new folder?

Comment: Do not mind what folder they are in now. Look at their package path and place them at the correct place. Create new folders (more formally packages) if they are currently missing.

Comment: Thank you, do you know where i can find package path?

Comment: It's usually at the top of `.java` source files. You should google for tutorials on Java packages.

Comment: Thank you. I just had to write package name of Main.class to TextIO - simply to add one line in the beggining - package com.company;.